# Присвоить переменной значение меняемого текстового поля

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребята, помогите разобраться 
есть переменная с текстовым значением, которая сетится в текстовое поле

```
var ex_text = 'hello world';
jQuery("#example").text(ex_text);
```

в дальнейшем значение текстового поля может меняться вручную пользователем
Как присвоить новой переменной значение уже изменившегося текста в `#example`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Событие `input` будет срабатывать после любого изменения значения textarea.

```js
var exText = 'Hello\nWorld';

var $example = $("#example");

$example.val(exText);
$example.on('input', function(){
  exText = $(this).val();
  
  console.clear();
  console.log(exText)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="example"></textarea>
```